# Some items do not display in SectionList until scroll trigger

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

When using `SectionList`, rows are not displayed though renderItem is called.
Rows appear immediately when scroll is triggered on the list.

I have found an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13316) to discuss about this issue, but i didn't find any solution to fix it. And The issue have been closed and mark to resolved issue.

The solution that have found in above issue is disable `removeClippedSubviews` in `SectionList` by set value to `false`. I see that this is do not solution, just a trick. With the huge of list, disable `removeClippedSubviews` will be terrible solution because it's don't optimize performance of list view.

I have been looking many hours, but dont have any solution to fix it. Have any suggest to fix this issue?

I have use:

```
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.55.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Using Props

```
<SectionList
maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}

....

/>
```

i Hope this will help.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, the above tricks didn't work

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, SectionList and Flatlist do not render all the items at once due to performance. They lazy load them instead. So you should use ScrollView instead.

Comment: ScrollView is not best choice for huge items

Comment: Also section headers are not easy to handle using ScrollView